# dataset changes not getting updated in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataset

I've created a data set via the Designer, and I'm able to retrieve data just fine.  After I do some updates to other data, I need to change the status in the original row.  I've scoured StackOverflow and MSDN, and I think I've tried everything suggested - no luck.

```
AFEDataSetTableAdapters.AFE_allTableAdapter taAFEAll = new AFEDataSetTableAdapters.AFE_allTableAdapter();
AFEDataSet.AFE_allDataTable dtAFEAll = new AFEDataSet.AFE_allDataTable();
taAFEAll.Fill(dtAFEAll, sAFENumber);
if (dtAFEAll.Count != 1)
{
    // error condition - should only ever be one row
}
DataRow drAFE = dtAFEAll.Rows[0];
```

// ...if everything goes well...

```
if (...successful...)
{
    drAFE.BeginEdit();
    drAFE["AFEStatus"] = "Published";
    drAFE.EndEdit();
    try
    {
        drAFE.AcceptChanges();
        int iTemp = taAFEAll.Update(dsAFE.AFE_all);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        sMessage = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

I've tried it with and without the BeginEdit, EndEdit, AcceptChanges; no change.  When the `.Update` method is invoked, I can see (in debug) that drAFE's ItemArray shows the changed value for AFEStatus.  The Update returns a zero, however, and the database doesn't change.

I verified in the code behind the DataSetDesigner, and the AFE_all table has an Update statement defined.

Where did I go wrong? or, what one-more-step(s) am I missing?

Comment: Forgot to mention - I have confirmed that a direct SQL update statement will change the database, using the credentials I supplied when defining the data set.  (Although I'm unsure how to verify what those were...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line

```
 drAFE.AcceptChanges();
```

The AcceptChanges() method 'changes' the state of the DataRow to Unchanged, so when you call the Update there is no row to save.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.acceptchanges.aspx)

> When you call AcceptChanges on the DataSet, any DataRow objects still
>   in edit-mode end their edits successfully. The RowState property of
>   each DataRow also changes; Added and Modified rows become Unchanged,
>   and Deleted rows are removed

Comment: "I've tried it with and without ... AcceptChanges" - sorry, that's not it.

Comment: Which is the value of the property drAFE.RowState after the EndEdit() call? It should be `Modified`

Comment: Steve - it does show as Modified, after the `drAFE.EndEdit` executes.

Comment: That's weird, unless the value you set is already the value of the column.

Comment: Definitely a changed value (from 'Approved' to 'Published'); I'm also changing a date column, that's not shown in the code snippet above.  Both columns show (in debug view) the changes occur, then the 'Modified' appears in the RowState ... and then, nothing.  No error, no change.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect the credentials don't have write priveleges, but (long story) I haven't finished verifying/testing that theory...

Comment: Could seems insane, but have you checked that your updates go to the correct database? Sometime the working database is in the DEBUG folder, while the database shown by Server Explorer is in the project folder

Comment: It's not a local db - it's SQL Server, on a separate server.

Comment: I thought I'd solved this, using different credentials - but, not so.  (I blame Monday Morning Mania...)  Even with credentials that have the correct privileges on the SQL Server db, this code is just not updating the db.